# springData mongodb group operation

Tags: mongodb

I have a list of list and i want to group on certain field and group data according to list.Example 
List>      // which is list of list username
and group all documents in according to list and field in document is username

```
List<List<String>> listOfUsernameList=new ArrayList<>();
listOfUsernameList.add(Arrays.asList("deep","pawan","kesar","ramesh"));
listOfUsernameList.add(Arrays.asList("paras","hema","mohan"));
listOfUsernameList.add(Arrays.asList("roshan","adil","aman"));
listOfUsernameList.add(Arrays.asList("mukesh","pankaj"));

And I want to group document like using springdata mongodb
{
    [{
    username:"deep",
    age:"25",
    subject:"physics"
     },
     {
    username:"kesar",
    age:"22",
    subject:"Maths"
     },
     {
    username:"pawan",
    age:"21",
    subject:"Chemistry"
     },
     {
    username:ramesh,
    age:"25",
    subject:"physics"
     }],
    [{
    username:"paras",
    age:"25",
    subject:"physics"
     },
     {
    username:"hema",
    age:"25",
    subject:"physics"
     }],
    [{
    username:"roshan",
    age:"25",
    subject:"physics"
     }],
    [{
    username:"mukesh",
    age:"28",
    subject:"physics"
     },
     {
    username:"pankaj",
    age:"25",
    subject:"physics"
     }]
}
```

Comment: Please post some details about your problem. like the input document structure with relevant fields, and what your expected output looks like, etc. Also, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please read how to [ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on Stackoverflow.